# Fully qualified class names in Laravel 5.2

Tags: namespaces, laravel-5

So as I'm working through various tutorials (laracast & YouTube), learning Laravel 5.2 I keep coming across this situation wherethe tutorial uses a namespace like

`App\Models\CarModel.php`

but it only works for me if I use

`carfreak\Models\CarModel.php`

It appears to be that for some reason my app demands a fully qualified class name, and the tutorials avoid it. How could I do the same?

My folder structure is as follows

```
myprojects
-project1
-project2
-carfreak
--app
---Console
---Events
---Exceptions
---Http
---Jobs
---Listners
---Models
----CarModel.php
---Policies
---Providers
--bootstrap
--config
--database
```

EDIT: My composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Models"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "carfreak\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

Comment: Where did you put your `Models` directory in `App` directory like this `App\Models`

Comment: Yep, that's right.

Comment: your question is not much clear, Please explain it little more

Comment: I create a new project by doing `laravel new carfreak` and then I have to use `carfreak` in prefacing my namespaces, whereas all the tutorials just use `App` as their prefix, regardless of the name of their app.

Comment: can you share your project directory structure?

Comment: It's pretty standard... just that I've moved Models into a directory of it's own. Please see edits above.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this will solve your issue, You just need to autoload your models directory. to do this you have to write this line `"app/Models"` in your `composer.json` file under `autoload -> class map array`. see below.

```
....
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Models"

    ]
   ...
},
```

When you add this, then Run this command in your terminal
`composer dump-autoload`

After that you can call your models like this
`use App\Models\Problem;`

Comment: I've added my json entry into the question above. 

The entry was there. but perhaps misspelt `/models` instead of `/Models`

Doesn't seem to have any effect. What about the psr-4 entry?